# Critical exponents and scaling dimension

Tags: resource-recommendations, conformal-field-theory, ising-model, critical-phenomena, scaling

It is often stated that the scaling exponents, e.g. $\alpha$ and $\beta$, of the critical 2D Ising model are related to the scaling dimensions $\Delta_{\sigma}$ and $\Delta_{\epsilon}$ of the operators $\sigma$ and $\epsilon$ as $$\alpha = \frac{2-d}{d- \Delta_{\epsilon}}$$ and $\beta = \Delta_{\sigma}/(1-\Delta_{\epsilon})$. Where can I find a proper derivation of this fact?